# Creating list ViewModels in the correct way

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, wpf, mvvm

I'm using Caliburn Micro to create a WPF application.

So what I want to do here is a typical Master/Detail situation. I'm displaying a list of Users and you can can add/edit a User and save the changes back to the database.

Everything works, but I'm just not sure if I'm creating the UserViewModels in the correct way. I lay awake at night yearning for a more elegant way.

Anything else that I'm doing wrong please let me know. It greatly helps me out and I appreciate every comment I get. Even if you must call me an idiot. Many thanks in advance!

PS: I left a few implementation details out to keep it brief. But let me know if anything else would help.

```
public class UserWorkspaceViewModel : Conductor<UserViewModel>.Collection.OneActive
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private UserViewModelFactory _userViewModelFactory;

    public UserWorkspaceViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserViewModelFactory userViewModelFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userViewModelFactory = userViewModelFactory;
        LoadUsers();
    }

    public void LoadUsers()
    {
        var users = _unitOfWork.Users.GetByDepartmentId(1);
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            // Use the factory to create the ViewModel
            UserViewModel viewModel = _userViewModelFactory.CreateInstance(user);

            // Caliburn Micro specific: add user to the screen collection
            this.Items.Add(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the UserViewModelFactory implementation:

```
public class UserViewModelFactory
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UserViewModelFactory(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public UserViewModel CreateInstance(User user)
    {
        UserViewModel vm = new UserViewModel(_unitOfWork);

        // Use AutoMapper to map properties from user to VM
        Mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(user, vm);

        return vm;
    }
}
```

And finally here's the UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel : Screen
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    #region Properties
    // Properties like FirstName, LastName, etc.
    #endregion

    public UserViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (this.Id == 0)
        {
            User user = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(this);
            _unitOfWork.Users.Add(user);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (this.Id > 0)
        {
            User user = _unitOfWork.Users.GetById(this.Id);
            Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(this, user);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for future reference, we prefer that you leave those details in. However, I think this question looks fine without them.

Answer (score 1):

- **UserWorkspaceViewModel**

  - `private UserViewModelFactory _userViewModelFactory;` instead of using the actual type use the interface like `private IUserViewModelFactory _userViewModelFactory;`
  - magic number `1` (`Users.GetByDepartmentId(1);`) should be expressed by a meaningful constant.
  - `LoadUsers()` method. Here IMHO you have used the `var` wrong. I don't think it is obvious what the right hand side of `var users = _unitOfWork.Users.GetByDepartmentId(1);` can be.

    ```
    List<User> users = _unitOfWork.Users.GetByDepartmentId(1);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {

    }
    ```

    would be more obvious.
- **UserViewModel**

  - the constructor won't compile, but I assume this is a copy & paste problem.

    ```
    public UserViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    ```
  - `Save()` method

    I guess it won't be possible for the Id property to become `<0` so a simple `else` instead of another `if` would be better.
    If the chances are high that you will need to add more code, consider to extract the adding and updating to separate methods.
- **General**

  Comments should explain **why** something is done. **What** is done should be explained by the code itself by using meaningful names for classes,methods and parameters. So comments like `// Use the factory to create the ViewMode` should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like keeping my post-constructor invariants `readonly` and ensuring they are valid with a guard clause as such:

```
public class UserViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    #region Properties
    // Properties like FirstName, LastName, etc.
    #endregion

    public UserViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
        }

        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // the rest
}
```